# I cannot figure out why this code results in a segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, yasm

I am using the yasm assembler on wsl2.

```
    segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax,1
```

I am compiling it in the following way

```
yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 -l task1.lst task1.asm
ld -o task1 task1.o
```

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that an exit code similar to C is required. so too fix this code just add

```
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```